Error in chaining proxies using the pyChainedProxy Python module
I have this python script I wrote to chain socks5 proxies from geonode.com using the pychainedproxy python module. It is a script I intend using for both network and system wide requests anonymity.
I store the proxies from the API's response in a proxies.txt file in this format:
socks5!192.168.1.1!80 /n
socks5!202.218.6.9!8080 /n
socks5!182.204.57.912!8080 /n
...
There are about 500 proxies and ports separated by an exclamation mark delimiter and afterwards, by a new line. (I used that delimiter because that is preferred to the colon (:), according to the module's documentation.
Using the socks.parseproxy() function, I intend to pass each line as a tuple to the adddefaultproxy() function and then unpack the arguments (socks5, proxy, port) to the function and then have it parse them and append to the chain.
The usage of the function is as is in the module's documentation, except in the documentation, the chain is a list of proxies.
When I run the code, it outputs the following error:
"Unexpected data has been received from the server"
When I looked up error specifications in the GitHub's repository, the error falls under the class GeneralProxyError. Here it is:
class GeneralProxyError - When thrown, it indicates a problem which does not fall
into another category. The parameter is a tuple containing an error code and a
description of the error, from the following list:
1 - invalid data - This error means that unexpected data has been received from
the server. The most common reason is that the server specified as the proxy is
not really a Socks4/Socks5/HTTP proxy, or maybe the proxy type specified is wrong.
From geonode's api, the proxies are socks5, and that is what is used in the code as well.
Here is the code:
#Importing dependencies
import pyChainedProxy as socks
import socket
import requests


url = 'https://proxylist.geonode.com/api/proxy-list?anonymityLevel=elite&protocols=socks5&filterUpTime=90&speed=fast&limit=500&page=1&sort_by=lastChecked&sort_type=desc'

#Making request to the API

response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()  # Check for HTTP request errors
page = response.json()

proxies = page['data']
# Loop through the list of proxies and passing the IP and each corresponding PORT value to a txt file

with open('proxies.txt', 'w') as file:
  
  for proxy in proxies:
      ip = proxy.get('ip') 
      port = proxy.get('port')
      protocols = proxy.get('protocols')
      proxy_type = ", ".join(protocols)
      file.write(f"{proxy_type}!{ip}!{port}\n")

with open('proxies.txt', 'r') as file:
    #Read the entire file content
    content = file.read()
    print(content)

def DEBUG(msg):
    print(msg)
socks.DEBUG = DEBUG

print("Check IP w/o proxyfying: ", requests.get('http://ip-api.com/json').content)

#PROXY_TYPE = socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5

with open('proxies.txt', 'r') as file:

 chain = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]  # Read proxies from file and strip any newlines

socks.setdefaultproxy()
for hop in chain:
    try:
        # Expect format: proxy:port
        proxy_address = hop.strip()  # No need to split, we assume the type is SOCKS5
        socks.adddefaultproxy(*socks.parseproxy(hop))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing proxy entry '{hop}': {e}")

# Replace socket with proxy-enabled one
rawsocket = socket.socket
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

# Print IP with proxy chain
print("Check IP with proxyfying: ", requests.get('http://ip-api.com/json').content)

What could the problem be?
I have tried replacing the exclaim mark with the colon, as well as directly sourcing the proxy type from the json rather than specifying it in the code.
